# Target WP7 and WP8.1 (Will 8.0 devices get the WP7 app)?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

If I target WP7 and WP8.1 then:

- Will WP8.0 devices be able to download the WP7 version?
- Will WP8.1 devices will get the WP8.1 version right ?

I'm developing an app I would like to target WP 7.1, 8.0 and 8.1.

I am thinking about targeting the 8.1 sdk for WP8. I am just not sure if that's a good idea right now as not all devices have gotten the 8.1 phone update.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to my knowledge:

- If your app is targeted to WP7 then it will be surely available for
  Both the WP8 and WP8.1 until and unless you have not provided the
  separate package for the later ones. so your first question's ans is
  *Yes*
- You said *thinking about targeting the 8.1 sdk for WP8* But before
  making this point explore that - Is it really worth or fruitful to do that
  because what is *New to WP8.1* will not be available for WP8 so
  what's pushing you for doing it.

As you already mentioned that WP8.1 devices are very few. I think this should not be the point of making decision. What your decision should depend on is - Are you going to use new features of WP8.1 in your app or not. If you are doing then you should also target WP8.1.
Because in the end every single user should have better experience of your App.

If you are trying to use common code for the WP8.1 and Windows 8.1 then you can also check for Universal Apps and Difference between WP8.1 Apps using Win-rt Apis and WP8.1 Silverlight apps because their are significant differences between the later ones.

Comment: I will use some WP8.0+ features as WP7 doesn't support some extended features I need for a more full featured app (like socket listening).  So if WP8.0 does everything I need I guess I'll stick with that SDK for WP8 and just have WP7 support with limited features... unless I run into an issue where I need WP8.1 support.

Comment: Also nice thing about WP8.1 is its API is much closer to Win8.1 which I will also support.

Comment: @zezba9000 check the update. I think it will be helpful.

Comment: Had thought of that, but according to this, 56% of WP users are on 8.0, not 8.1: http://www.wpcentral.com/new-adduplex-stats-show-windows-phone-81-now-244-percent-device

So I guess unless I run into something I will stick with 8.0.